# wrongly show ical event end date in ios

Tags: ios, icalendar, eventkit, nscalendar, ekevent

I am working on ical event. i add some events in ical. that event

start Date:26 Sep 1.00pm

end date:5 oct 2.00 pm

recurrence end date:5 apr 2014

i loaded all ical event in my app. but it shows different end date. end date is same as recurrence end date.

```
  "EKEvent <0x1d9ed060> {EKEvent <0x1d9ed060> {title = Gt 45; location = ; calendar =  
 EKCalendar <0x1d9ea1b0> {title = Google; type = CalDAV; allowsModify = YES; color =    
 #0e61b9;}; alarms = (null); URL = (null); lastModified = 2013-09-26 06:36:37 +0000;  
 timeZone    = Asia/Kolkata (IST) offset 19800}; location = ; startDate = 2014-03-26 
 07:30:00 +0000; endDate = 2014-04-04 08:30:00 +0000; allDay = 0; floating = 0; 
 recurrence = EKRecurrenceRule <0x1d9d0f80> RRULE
 FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20140405T182959Z; attendees = (null)}"
```

If i am not setting recurrence then start and end date is correct what i have to set.

Comment: Check  the time zone of your device and date.. When you log a NSDate convert them to the local time zone.

Comment: yes i did. problem is if i am not setting recurrence it shows correct end date. if i set recurrence event then event end date is same as recurrence end date.

Comment: hi krishnan, not time zone issue. i entered end date is oct 5, so if it is time zone issue means i will get near oct 6, or oct 4. but in my application event end date is "endDate = 2014-04-04 08:30:00 +0000"

Comment: Ok ..I did not notice that..

Comment: the starDate in your output does not match what you indicated as being the startdate. Or are you showing the last instance of the event after expansion ?